# What was it that gave IT/ME away?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, prepositions, sentence-meaning

I asked a person to guess my nationality from my accent. And after a few attempts he figured it out. Then I said:

"What was it that that gave **it/me** away?"

I'm not sure if I should use 'it' or 'me' here and what difference they make.
Can I also say- "What gave it/me away."

Comment: "What gave it/me away?" is also fine, yes. Personally I would prefer that cause it's simpler and less formal.

Answer (score 16):

Either. Your accent gave *it* (your nationality) away, or it gave *you* away as a person of that nationality.

Comment: This is correct. To expand a little: "What gave *it* away?" = "What clue led you to the answer?"  "What gave *me* away" = "What clue did I let slip / What mistake did I make in my attempt to conceal the answer?"  They're mostly interchangeable but if deception or concealment was really desired, you'd go with *me* and not *it*.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm still a little confused about 'me'. What gave IT away= my nationality, and what  gave me  way=??

Comment: If your accent gives _you_ away, it betrays the fact that you are a _person_ of a particular nationality, or from a particular region.

Comment: Thank you once again. So it is- It- my nationality and, me= me as a person who I was trying to hide.

Comment: Yes - although it doesn't necessarily mean that you are trying to hide what you are. You said you had asked someone to guess your nationality!